# How can the postal address of the intercompany customer be displayed?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to display the address for direct delivery in intercompany Transaction for the customer in field `SalesTable.IntercompanyOriginalCustAccount`. I can get the customer record, which I need to show the address for that customer. But when I change the customer address, the address returned by the following code is empty.

```cs
display public LogisticsAddressing getAlamat()
{
    CustTable                   custTable;
    DirPartyTable               dirPartyTable;
    LogisticsPostalAddress      logisticsPostalAddress;
    LogisticsAddressing         alamat;
    CustAccount                 intercompanyCust = this.InterCompanyOriginalCustAccount;

    alamat = "";
    changeCompany('ma-d')
    {
        while select firstOnly custTable
                order by logisticsPostalAddress.RecId desc
                where intercompanyCust == custTable.AccountNum
            join dirPartyTable
                where dirPartyTable.RecId == custTable.Party
            join logisticsPostalAddress
                where logisticsPostalAddress.location == dirPartyTable.PrimaryAddressLocation
                   //&& logisticsPostalAddress.recVersion == 1
        {
            alamat=logisticsPostalAddress.Address;
        }
    }
    return alamat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fulfills your requirements, but take a look at the `postalAddress` method of table `CustTable`. Using this, your code could look like the following:

```cs
display public LogisticsAddressing getAlamat()
{
    CustTable                   custTable;
    LogisticsPostalAddress      logisticsPostalAddress;
    LogisticsAddressing         alamat;

    changeCompany(this.InterCompanyCompanyId)
    {
        custTable = CustTable::find(this.InterCompanyOriginalCustAccount);
        logisticsPostalAddress = custTable.postalAddress();
        alamat = logisticsPostalAddress.Address;
    }
    return alamat;
}
```